# co browsing with tablet

Tags: bluetooth, labview

I would like to co browse from my tablet to my desktop, but have several questions in regard to this.

1) Can a simple bluetooth link provide the connection?

2) If the "Host" is a desktop, is the desktop doing all the processing?

3) Long story short, I want to know if I can develop or alter a LabVIEW VI on a tablet if co browsing on the desktop that has the software on it.

Comment: You have [teamviewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.teamviewer.market.mobile&hl=en) for android, with which you can control your PC. I believe it requires an internet connection.

Comment: As suggested by berna1111, with teamviewer you can remotely control a PC/Tablet which is great for updating/maintaining/supporting software on a remote location at a client. (Haven't seen this being don via bluetooth yet, I would expect it is to low latency).

Comment: As to the short story could you clarify the question a bit. The suggested methods work but only if the device on which you want to alter the VI has a Labview development suite on it. Could you also clarify co browsing a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Long story short, I want to know if I can develop or alter a LabVIEW
>   VI on a tablet if co browsing on the desktop that has the software on
>   it.

Yes you can.  I used to use Google chrome remote desktop to access a pc in a contract manufacturers and would edit and update the LabVIEW code as required using that method.